# отклик на запрет использования фотокамеры

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Я делаю приложение которому необходим доступ фотокамере. При первом нажатии на кнопку "сделать фото" появляется системный алерт (как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]) для разрешения доступа к камере. Как получить отклик, если пользователь нажимает "Запретить"?? Хочу в этом случае сразу выдавать другой алерт.

Comment: Можете добавить Ваш код в вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Для отклика можно использовать такой код:

```
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo 
                 completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
    if (granted) {
        // пользователь дал доступ
    } else {
        // пользователь запретил доступ
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Следует использовать следующее

```
func configurePermissions() {

        func requestCameraPermission() {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { [unowned self] granted in
                if granted {
                    self.setupCamera()
                } else {
                    // TODO: User cancel permission
                }
            }
        }

        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) {
        case .notDetermined:
            requestCameraPermission()
        case .authorized:
            setupCamera()
        default:
            // TODO: Show Alert with route to Settings
            break
        }
    }
```